# SQL Server OUTER JOIN results limited by WHERE criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have 2 SQL Server database tables that I'm designing a report for using Crystal Reports. The first table provides a list of all offices that take applications and the second includes a list of all the applications.

The report I'm designing is supposed to show headers for all offices (needs to be present because there’s a separate subreport that is pulling under each of these sections in CR). The report then provides totals for any applications that have been received year-to-date. The SQL query works fine until I add the WHERE clause to limit the applications taken in 2018 – then it shows me only the offices that have had applications in 2018.

From what I’ve found while searching for answers, SQL treats the OUTER JOIN as an INNER JOIN once the date criteria on the right-hand table is added, so I believe this to be the case. However, if I leave out the date criteria, then obviously I receive all applications...ever. I’m trying to figure out if I’m missing something apparent or if I need to use a different type of SQL query to accomplish what I’m looking for.

Here is the query I'm currently working with and would appreciate any suggestions for how to make this work.

```
SELECT office.src_office_id
FROM source_office office
FULL OUTER JOIN  credit_application app ON app.src_office_id = office.src_office_id
WHERE office.src_office_id IS NOT NULL OR
  (app.delete_app=0
   AND (app.data_entry_complete >= {ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'} 
   AND app.data_entry_complete < {ts '2018-09-11 00:00:00'}))
ORDER BY office.src_office_id ASC
```

Comment: From what I understand you want an outer join.
However, by saying `office.src_office_id IS NOT NULL` you basically make it a right join with the exception of those entries caught by the second condition.
You probably want to remove the `NOT `

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you edited your question and described the schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements) along with sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and the result you expect with that sample data.

Comment: Hi. Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join".

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: @NielsNet It's not that NULL test that removes null-extended rows, it's the OR requiring the right table columns to be non-null that does it. (See the accepted answer.) Of course it's *often* a IS NOT NULL of a right table column that is the way that these faqs "turn outer join into inner join".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE office.src_office_id IS NOT NULL
```

this would not do anything in this case since you are already filtering out the non existent `office.src_office_id` by using an outer join.

You can do a left join and add your date filter with the join itself

```
LEFT JOIN 
  credit_application app 
    ON app.src_office_id = office.src_office_id 
    AND app.delete_app=0 
    AND (app.data_entry_complete >= {ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'} 
    AND app.data_entry_complete < {ts '2018-09-11 00:00:00'}
```

then do

```
WHERE office.src_office_id IS NOT NULL
```

sorry maybe for the wrong syntax, hope you understand what I mean, you would load into a set the offices and application based on the date, then filter out those applications without an office.

Comment: This actually works perfectly and provides exactly the results I'm looking for! Thank you!!